# R Check If Values Exist in Groups

Tags: r, data.table

```
data=data.frame(    StudentID   =c( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7   ),
    cat =c( NA,'a.b','p','o','a.b','cb',NA    ),
    fox =c( 'c.e','qq',NA,'i','k','c.b',NA  ),
    dog =c( 'zz','u','e.W','h','g','f',NA   ))
library(reshape2)
data1 = melt(data, id.vars = "StudentID")

dataWANT=data.frame(    StudentID   =c( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7   ),
    WANT1   =c( 1,1,1,0,1,0,NA  ),
    WANT2   =c( 'c.e','a.b','e.W','NA','a.b','NA','NA'  ))
```

I have 'data' and wish to create 'dataWANT' which contains in 'WANT1' a score value of '1' if any string in 'cat' or 'fox' or 'dog' contains 'a.b' OR 'c.e' or "e.W'; if not 'WANT1' equals to zero and if all 'cat' and 'fox' and 'dog' are NA than WANT equals to 'NA'. Then 'WANT2' equals to the first occurence of the select values.

A data.table solution is desired!

Comment: BTW: the [tag:data.table] tag is specific to the [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html), which is distinct in many ways from R's base `data.frame`. I changed the tag; if I'm mistaken, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create the 'WANT1' column with `Reduce` and `%in%` loop over the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), check whether the elements are `%in%` the vector of values, `Reduce` it to a single logical `vector` with `|`, and change the rows where all 'cat', 'fox', 'dog' are NA to NA in 'WANT1'.  With `WANT2`, we can use `fcoalesce` after `replace`ing the values other than the desired to `NA`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, WANT1 := +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, function(x)
       x %in% c('a.b', 'c.e', 'e.W')))), .SDcols = cat:dog]
data[is.na(cat) & is.na(fox)& is.na(dog), WANT1 := NA]
data[, WANT2 := do.call(fcoalesce, lapply(.SD,
       function(x) replace(x,  !x %in% c('a.b', 'c.e', 'e.W'), NA))), 
        .SDcols = cat:dog]
data[, .(StudentID, WANT1, WANT2)]
#   StudentID WANT1 WANT2
#1:         1     1   c.e
#2:         2     1   a.b
#3:         3     1   e.W
#4:         4     0  <NA>
#5:         5     1   a.b
#6:         6     0  <NA>
#7:         7    NA  <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

## dplyr/tidyr

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
wants <- c("c.e", "e.W", "a.b")
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cat:dog, names_to = "pet", values_to = "val") %>%
  group_by(StudentID) %>%
  summarize(
    WANT2 = intersect(wants, val)[1],
    WANT1 = if (all(is.na(val))) NA_integer_ else (+(!is.na(WANT2)))
  )
# # A tibble: 7 x 3
#   StudentID WANT2 WANT1
#       <dbl> <chr> <int>
# 1         1 c.e       1
# 2         2 a.b       1
# 3         3 e.W       1
# 4         4 <NA>      0
# 5         5 a.b       1
# 6         6 <NA>      0
# 7         7 <NA>     NA
```

(Normally, `intersect` will return a vector of length 0 when nothing is common. The `[1]` forces something, as `character(0)[1]` returns `NA`.)

---

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(    StudentID   =c( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7   ),
    cat =c( NA,'a.b','p','o','a.b','cb',NA    ),
    fox =c( 'c.e','qq',NA,'i','k','c.b',NA  ),
    dog =c( 'zz','u','e.W','h','g','f',NA   ))

data.table::melt(dat, id.vars="StudentID")[
  , .(WANT1 = if (all(is.na(value))) NA_integer_ else 1L,
      WANT2 = intersect(value, wants)[1]), by = .(StudentID)
  ][, WANT1 := fifelse(is.na(WANT1), WANT1, +(!is.na(WANT2)))
  ][]
#    StudentID WANT1 WANT2
# 1:         1     1   c.e
# 2:         2     1   a.b
# 3:         3     1   e.W
# 4:         4     0  <NA>
# 5:         5     1   a.b
# 6:         6     0  <NA>
# 7:         7    NA  <NA>
```

Comment: it is perfect thanks so much what if I need to modify it so instead of "c.e" for example it includes any string with "c.e" such as "c.e5" or "c.e.q"  ? thanks a bunch!

Comment: Just update the `wants` variable, that's why it's there: update that one and re-run the code, all should work.

Comment: You changed it back to [tag:data.table], does that mean you are looking for a `data.table` solution? If so, then using the `data.frame(...)` function is just wrong/distracting.

Comment: When you asked about `"c.e"` and `"c.e5"` or `"c.e.q"`, did you mean *patterns*? If so, you need to be clear on your constraints, since that can get "fun".

Comment: thanks so much yes a data.table solution since there is big data set but your solution is working so far. I guess for the 'wants' variable I am wondering how can i include ALL measures that include "c.e" without having to list them all? for example there may be over 50 for each type but the core is "c.e" for example

Comment: yes i apologize i did not know about the patterns function. so it is patterns of "c.e" and "e.W" and "a.b"

Comment: There is no patterns function ... but you question suggests either spiraling requirements on the question or things are unclear. So please be specific: are you looking for *exact* matches (set membership), or some form of pattern, where it could be *anywhere*, at the *beginning* of the string, or something else?

Comment: If you don't want regular expressions (they can get powerful or messy), consider `grep("^c\\.e.*", unlist(dat), value = TRUE)` that returns all occurrences of strings that begin with `"c.e"`. Similarly for other patterns you might have.

Comment: Does that resolve your immediate problem of programmatically defining `wants`?